# Error while uploading iOS app to AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, app-store, appstore-approval

While I upload my iOS app to appStore with "Distribute" button from Xcode, I get this error:

[image]

However, I uploaded the icons to Xcode:

[image]

I dont understand what is the problem exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the icons are in correct size.

Comment: Icon sizes are correct. Is there any regulation about, icon file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about archiving the application. After solving errors, it must be archived each time. I forgot to do this.